# Meteor: Call template helper from other template

Tags: meteor

I have two templates and I've defined JavaScript helpers and events to go with each. When a button is clicked in template A, one of the things I want to do is call a helper function for template B which will change what's displayed on the screen. Is this possible?

If it's not possible, I'd instead like to reload template B.

How can I do either of these? Do I use Tracker.autorun? Reactive variables? Ideally I would do, inside an event function for template A,

```
    B.helpers.call("helperFunctionFromTemplateB");
```

Answer (score 2):

There are *a lot* of solutions to what I think you want to achieve, but the answer really depends on context.

1. If template A is a child template of B:

   1. You can pass  a reference to a [ReactiveVar](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-var) in the parent template down to the child template's data context and modify it using `{{>childTemplate reactiveVar=reactiveVar}}` where `reactiveVar` is a helper in the parent template that returns the reference to the reactive variable
   2. If the thing you want to change is in the parent's data context, you can use `Template.parentData(n)` where `n`is the amount of levels you want to jump up. While modifying the parent's data may not immediately seem reactive, you can make the `data` prop reactive by accessing it via `Template.currentData()`
2. Use some kind of globally accessible state. The most common answer would probably be to use the [Session](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/session) package and use `Session.get('var')` and `Session.set('var', val)`.
3. Use an [event emitter](https://atmospherejs.com/raix/eventemitter). This approach gets +'s for decoupling and reusability, but it's also potentially heavy handed if you only need to modify this variable in one place from one source (i.e. your requirements are simple)
4. **Meteor 1.3** - If you want to make references to your reactive data in multiple places but don't want to create a global like `Session`, use a ReactiveVar or [Reactive Dict](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-dict) (closer to session), create your variable where it makes sense, `export` it, and `import` it in your templates/anywhere else to be used.

There's a lot of other solutions, these are just the first that come to mind. If you provide more specific context, I'll provide a code sample of what I think's best and explain why. :)